# Restore renv locally without redownloading packages in Shiny Dockerfile

Tags: r, docker, shiny, renv

I'm trying to build a dockerfile for my shinyapp. There are many libraries to install Shinyapp needs. That's why, you need to define all packages in second RUN layer one by one.

For example:

```
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('renv', 'shiny', 'tidyverse', ...), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"
```

However, installing all packages can take too much time. I want to avoid wasting time and use renv in Dockerfile.

When using renv::restore(), it redownloads all packages instead of using them locally. I couldn't figure out how to arrange my dockerfile to avoid this issue.

I already installed all packages with renv in the project directory. How can I avoid redownloading and rebuilding the packages, when building a dockerfile?

```
FROM openanalytics/r-base

LABEL maintainer  "Tobias Verbeke <tobias.verbeke@openanalytics.eu>"

# https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/#/repos/2/packages/A3
# system libraries of general use
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    nano \
    make \
    automake \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libicu-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libfontconfig1-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libfribidi-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libharfbuzz-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libtiff-dev \
    libglpk-dev \
    libgmp3-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libssl1.1 \
    libmpfr-dev 
    
# install shiny packages
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('renv'), repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"

# Create Directory
RUN mkdir /root/Project

# copy the app to the image
COPY Project /root/Project

# copy all virtual environment files
COPY renv.lock /root/Project/renv.lock
COPY renv /root/Project/renv
COPY .Rprofile /root/Project/.Rprofile

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e", "renv::restore(); shiny::runApp('/root/Project')"]
```